# How to select a Web API OData Controller scaffold when creating a new controller in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, odata, asp.net-web-api

[This](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/creating-an-odata-endpoint) post shows an option creating a controller with the "Web API OData Controller" scaffold right from the Add New/Controller menu option in Visual Studio - [IMAGE HERE](http://i2.asp.net/media/4407657/odata06.PNG?cdn_id=2013-10-18-001)

I have added the Nuget packages for OData and WebApi, and only see the WebApi Controller scaffold option.  The closest option I have is "API controller with read/write actions using Entity Framework".

I also noticed the UI is a bit different than in my VS 2012, and there is a "[Web Api Controller Class (v2)](http://i1.asp.net/media/4407651/odata05.png?cdn_id=2013-10-18-001)" option in their list.

How do I get this to appear in my IDE?

Comment: The OData controller scaffolding is only available in VS2013.

Comment: Boo.  Is there a way to implement this in 2012?

Comment: @ElHaix: we are bringing this support to VS 2012 in our next release